# Writing a configurable git command in bash script

Tags: git, bash, github, git-log

Take a git command  as below-

```
git log --before="$today" --after="yeasterday" --pretty=format "%cd"
```

i want my script to do this -

a user inputs any of date/author/commit#..... etc.
Whichever the user provides use it in the command and provide log- something like:

If user provides only after-date add that part of command to the `git log`

```
git log $afterdate
```

where `$afterdate= "--after=user_provided_date_goes here"`

Is this possible using Bash script. i tried as showed above by concatenating `git log` to `$command` to get desired log output didn't work(it fails to build a command as such)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a custom git command. You just need to create a script that is named `git-<customCommandName>` and make it available in the `PATH`, and executable, of course. For example, to add a new command that shows last N number of merge commits I'd create a file named `git-show-merge-commits` with the content,

```
#!/bin/sh

NUM=$1

git log --merges -n $NUM
```

And then you go into your repository and type,

```
$ git show-merge-commits 4
```

Voila.